# How use the Google Drive like a web Service

Tags: android

I'm trying to create an app and use the Google Drive like a webService to this app, I'll store some files in my Drive account (like images and audios), and when the user click in a button (of download), will be done the download of the chosen file to his phone. However when I try to connect  to my Drive account, the app displays a dialog asking to user choose a account (of his phone), but I should inform my account programmatically (and the user should not have knowledge of it). Just press the button and that is it. Anyone please, knows how I should inform my account in my code:

My code:

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Drive.API)
                    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
        }
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();//this will kick the code to onConnectionFailed() (cause no account was informed)
    }
```

and here on onConnectionFailed() is the code that opens the dialog

```
@Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        if (!result.hasResolution()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Erro! " + result.toString());
            return;
        }

        try {
            //open the dialog
            result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);
        } catch (SendIntentException e) {

        }
    }
```

Anyone knows how and where I have to inform my account in order to directly set up my account and makes the dialog does not open

- And also how I can make the log out after the download (to my account does not stay exposed)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include and account name in `Builder`:

```
 GoogleApiClient client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
         .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */,
             this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
         .addApi(Plus.API)
         .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
         .setAccountName("users.account.name@gmail.com")
         .build();
```

But this does not mean it's a good idea though.

Take a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/

Comment: Hi Diego, thanks for your answer. But why it would not be the good idea? Do you think that my account will be too much exposed? I'm new in this, then this way seems to me like a free webService... Have you other idea, or a good webService to indicate? Thanks...

Comment: Are you looking for a [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network)?

Comment: I think so. :) Like I said I'm newly graduated and I'm little bit lost. What I want is store files like images and audios for example, so the user of my app could download just pressing a button (like any other normal app) without know of where this download is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to host files for your application online for free, I would actually use dropbox. There would be no prompt for the user (other than how they want to download it[which can also be avoided]) But all you have to do is download the file using the standard android downloader, and change the dropbox url from `dropbox.com/...` to `dl.dropbox.com` or `user.dropbox.com` (can't remember which, it's been a while. If you want to update the files, just drag them into you dropbox WITH THE SAME NAME as the old file, and they will be updated without changing their url. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. Good idea. I'll try.